# Randomly selecting numbers from n consecutive numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given an integer array of n consecutive number from 0, i.e.

```
0,1,2,..n
```

I wish to select `n/2` numbers randomly.

Say `n=5`
Then a possible set would be `0,3,5`.

How to achieve that easily?

Comment: With duplicates allowed or without?

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the numbers and determine the probability that each number should be in the result:

```
int n = 5;
int left = (n + 1) / 2;
int[] result = new int[left];
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; left > 0; i++) {
  if (rnd.Next(n + 1 - i) < left) {
    result[result.Length - left] = i;
    left--;
  }
}
```

Note: This will always produce a sorted result.

#### Edit:

Here is a tests run creating 200000000 results, counting the combinations generated (where the binary number represents the combination, e.g. 100110 is 0,3,4):

```
010011 : 9999164
110001 : 10003346
010101 : 9990975
100101 : 9998154
101001 : 10006305
100110 : 10003350
101010 : 10000583
101100 : 9995335
011001 : 10000007
001011 : 10001492
001110 : 10001158
100011 : 9994680
110100 : 9998226
110010 : 9999954
011010 : 10002269
000111 : 10004752
010110 : 9996886
011100 : 9999196
111000 : 10001094
001101 : 10003074
```

Comment: Really nice that one. Does it work because the probability of selection at each step is left/ remaining ?

Comment: @CrisStringfellow: Yes, exactly.

Comment: That is pretty nifty. What led you to that? Where else can you use that construction ? I'm interested since I rarely think from that way but I know it's powerful.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow: A friend showed me the theory about 25 years ago, implemented as a BASIC program, and I have used it a few times since, implemented in different languages. You can use it to pick items randomly without duplicates, but that's the only use I found for it.

Comment: Could someone provide a pointer to an analysis showing this does not introduce correlations between consecutive values? My intuition is that 4 and 5 will either both or neither be selected with increased probability depending on how many numbers were selected early, creating a correlation between them. However, intuition is no substitute for mathematical analysis.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: The probability calculation is independend on which previous number was added, so there is no bias. I added a test result above, showing that there is no bias towards any combination.

Comment: @Guffa Looks good experimentally. I'm still interested in finding a formal analysis before adding this to my toolkit.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I'm not sure what you are looking for. The algorithm is very straightforward; it calculates the probability for each number to be included in the result based on how many numbers are left and how many of those should be picked, and the number is picked if the random number falls within the probability.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I've found of doing this is an incomplete [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Stop after n/2 iterations.

The shuffle in effect works with two arrays, the randomly selected numbers and the pool of numbers that have not yet been used, and therefore are available for selection. As it happens the total size of the two arrays is the original array length, so they can be stored in place by partitioning.

After n/2 iterations, the partition representing the numbers that have been selected is a random choice from the original array.

Another way of looking at this is that the first n/2 numbers of the result of the full shuffle will not be changed by the n/2+1 or subsequent iterations of the shuffle.

Comment: @MitchWheat Could you explain why you would expect bias?

Comment: If that introduced bias, the full shuffle would have the same bias in the part that the first n/2 iterations filled (and the reversed bias in the other half, I suppose)

Comment: @MitchWheat it doesn't change the part that it has already output, so it has to be without bias from the start

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), then pick the first `n/2` items in the array.

As @Patricia Shanahan points out in her answer, it is only necessary to shuffle the first `n/2` items in the array using Fisher-Yates.

Comment: In practice, I would use the full shuffle if the required size is a significant fraction of the total size, and I had a full shuffle implementation already available. I would use the incomplete shuffle if I needed to write it from scratch anyway, or if there is a big savings in the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to generate index of the vector numbers by using Random object with Next. You add a new generate value to an structure like ArrayList or HashSet to memorize that. For every new generating of the index you verify if that value is present or not in this structure.

Answer (score 0):

A method that efficiently uses the properties of binary to encode the selection is :

1. Generate a random 32-bit unsigned int.
2. Do this n/32 times, and put these in an array called masks
3. The bits of these random ints select the number selected. Specifically if the word size is 32 then i will be selected if (masks[i/32] >> (i%32)) && 1 is true.

Since random 32 bit ints will on average have 16 0s and 16 1s this method will get close to your value of n/2.

Say the actual number of 1s you get is W and differs from n/2 by k, k = W - n/2

If you have k too few numbers selected generate a random integer in range 0 to n, go to that bit indexed by that number and change the first 0 you encounter to a 1, searching forward.

Do this k times.

In the case where you have k too many, change the first 1 you encounter to a zero.

The advantage if this is it is also the most compact structure to store you subset, with each bit selecting a single integer. You only need to range, and this array of masks, and you have your selection.

Plus you have to generate 16 times less random numbers than the other shuffle methods making it more efficient.

Finally, this increase in efficiency increases with word size. For 64 bit unsigned longs you get 32 times less random numbers required than by the "n/2 swaps permutation method"

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is Linq not allowed when you write `algorithm`?

```
int[] arrInts = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
var r = new Random();
var randomInts = arrInts.OrderBy(i => r.Next(arrInts.Length))
                        .Take(arrInts.Length/2)
                        .ToArray();
```

Edit: I am not 100% sure about performance, but it might be better to use `.AsParallel()` before `.OrderBy()`.

I like using Linq because it is very readable and it took me around 5 secs to write the algorithm instead of many minutes to write sorting and looping "by hand".